# Error connecting to WCF service with Windows security

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis, windows-authentication

I have a client connecting to a WCF service using the following on both endpoints:

```
<security mode="Message">
  <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

This works in my dev environment (both running locally) and the negotiation works properly. When I push it to the test environment I get the following message:

> SOAP security negotiation with '**http://host/service**' for target
>   '**http://host/service**' failed. See inner exception for more details.

The inner exception:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Security Support Provider
>   Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. The server may not be running
>   in an account with identity '**host/server-name.domain**'. If the
>   server is running in a service account (Network Service for example),
>   specify the account's ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the
>   EndpointAddress for the server. If the server is running in a user
>   account, specify the account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in
>   the EndpointAddress for the server.

After randomly changing attributes and generally messing about, the only way I could get it working was to change the Application Pool for the service to use LocalSystem as the Identity.  This has subsequently caused the sys admins to have kittens, and is not something I can continue doing.

Can anyone shed any light as to why this is happening? Both the client Windows account, and the AppPool's Identity are in the same domain. The service is running on a server in the same domain.

Answer (score 3):

If authentication works with LocalSystem but not a domain account it may be that you're missing a SPN for the domain account. This page provides some background about configuring the identity that your service is running as: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx

Comment: Just a thought, could that be the case if the machine was set up as a VM from a template (ie cloned)?

Comment: I'm not sure that the machine being cloned (or not) will impact this. AFAIK to use Kerberos the service identity requires a valid SPN/UPN.